# Edit CC Code Transational Emails Magento

Tags: php, magento

When  someone order in my website using credit card Magento send an email with a lot of details about the order. This email show the payment method was used, but out instead of being a name written on the card is the code, how do I do to change this variable in magento.

This is my Transational Email Code(Just payment part):

```
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th align="left" width="325" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:5px 9px 6px 9px; line-height:1em;">Informa&ccedil;&otilde;es de Cobran&ccedil;a:</th>
                        <th width="10"></th>
                        <th align="left" width="325" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:5px 9px 6px 9px; line-height:1em;">Forma de Pagamento:</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top" style="font-size:12px; padding:7px 9px 9px 9px; border-left:1px solid #EAEAEA; border-bottom:1px solid #EAEAEA; border-right:1px solid #EAEAEA;">
                            {{var order.getBillingAddress().format('html')}}
                        </td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td valign="top" style="font-size:12px; padding:7px 9px 9px 9px; border-left:1px solid #EAEAEA; border-bottom:1px solid #EAEAEA; border-right:1px solid #EAEAEA;">
                            {{var payment_html}}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

This is the email:

[Transational email http://imageshack.com/a/img10/4623/yo23.jpg](http://imageshack.com/a/img10/4623/yo23.jpg)